# Extracting certain values from the Pandas Series with float64 datatype

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas series with float64 datatype, and I would like to extract certain values from that series.

Example, `x=pd.Series([1.0, 1.4, 1.8, 2.0, 2.6, 3.0],copy=False)`

I would like to extract only "1.0, 2.0 and 3.0" from the above series, x. How can I achieve it?

Comment: How do you want to extract them? By their index (i.e., position), or by their absolute value, etc? And how should the output look like?

Comment: Hi @ Sandertjuhh, my expected output should be in the list - out = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0].

Comment: so you're checking for whole numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the indices of your numbers, you can do this:

```
x = pd.Series([1.0, 1.4, 1.8, 2.0, 2.6, 3.0],copy=False)
x.iloc[[0, 3, 5]].tolist()
>>> [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

If you want to extract only those floats that are whole numbers:

```
x = pd.Series([1.0, 1.4, 1.8, 2.0, 2.6, 3.0],copy=False)
[i for i in x if i.is_integer()]
>>> [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Since some information is missing in your question, these solutions might not meet your requirements. If that is the case, please clarify your question.